# Position UILabel when app is opened in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uilabel, xib, universal

I have a universal iPhone/iPad app. On the main menu I have a UIImage and UILabel that show the current weather conditions outside; the UILabel shows the current temperature.

I am using the same XIB for both versions, I made all of the graphics I am using a high resolution so they scale good for the iPad.

On the iPhone version, right under the UIImage the label is centered, which is what I want it to do. When it loads in the iPad, the UIImage gets a big bigger, but the label stays in the same position, to the left of the screen, not centered under the bigger image. I have tried many different things in IB to get it to center, and I cannot get it to.

Would it also be possible to make the text size bigger when loaded on the iPad?

Here are some images to portray what I am talking about:

iPhone version:
http://img855.imageshack.us/i/iphonei.png/

iPad version:
http://img163.imageshack.us/i/ipadh.png/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your label issue, but to vary text size for iPad create a function to test if you're on an iPad and then use that to vary your code as required. Here's a function to to do the job.

```
BOOL isIPad()
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

And then just write some conditional code. For example:

```
UIButton *infoCircle;

    if (isIPad())
    {
        infoCircle =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
    }
    else
    {
        infoCircle =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    }
```

In your case, you'll want to adjust the label font size with something like:

```
if (isIPad())
{
      [[self mainLabel] setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 18.0]];
}
else
{
      [[self mainLabel] setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0]];
}
```

If Interface Builder is giving you grief, you can also use the same approach to reposition the UILabel programmatically. Sometimes this is quicker, especially once your interface has settled down.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to position the label correctly and set the TextAlignment to left to get it where I want it. I was still unable to get the text size bigger in the label; I tried using sizeWithFont but it did not change the font size.

Comment: Added some code to my answer that I use in my app that get the text size to change in the label. Depending how you are sizing the UILabel you might need to adjust the CGRect you are using to set the frame or send the label a sizeToFit message after you've set the label up and added it to a view. Hope this helps. If you've set label in IB, you might want to double check you've not set the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property. If you have, the iOS will shrink the font size to the label size. WHich, in your case, might not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks the font size now adjusts!